# Android SDK ICS flash fullscreen -> crash

Tags: android

In my application I've got a webview where a flash player is embedded. The app runs perfect on devices with an android version < 4.0. On devices with ICS the app crashes when the user wants to start the flash player, because it directly enters fullscreen mode. 
I googled around a lot and found a workaround to solve this problem:
`mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){ ... });`

Now after starting the player, it won't crash anymore, but the webview gets invisible.

So I want to ask, if there is any solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get the solution for this problem? I am also getting this issue. Can you please help me?